# Edit imported osm maps on GeoServer with iD or Potlatch 2

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, editing

I have installed geoserver on Ubuntu and imported osm map data into it. Now I want to attach  a map editor(iD or potlatch 2) to this suite to edit maps but I have not a clue. Any help or documentation? 
In the near future I will need to get change sets and also upload my changes to osm. Is it possible to do this?